# Automated Recurring Billing system Paid Memberships Pro wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, authorize.net

I enabled recurring system on website but when any member signup or create account, it generates me a error:

**"Automated Recurring Billing is not enabled. A partial payment was made that we could not void. Please contact the site owner immediately to correct this."**

I try to find error but paid membership pro documentation or forum give access only premium users.
I am using plugin version 1.7.11 and wordpress version is:3.8.3.

Demo Link: http://www.butterflyclubtribe.com/sign-me-up/?level=1

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not certain this is an error generated by PayPal, Recurring Billing would have to be enabled on the account to create Recurring Billing Profiles in the live environment. Have a look at [Recurring Billing Service: FAQs](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-recurring-billing-faq-outside).

Comment: Jason from PMPro here.

Yes, OP should make sure that ARB is enabled. Sometimes you have to call in to make sure.

What's happening here is we are making the first one-time payment and then failing to setup the subscription payment (that "Automated Recurring Billing is not enabled" message is from PayPal, the rest is from PMPro). When this happens, we try to back track the initial payment that was made and throw that combined error.

Comment: It seems the URL you added in the answer is not working and removed by PayPal. Please update the answer. Thanks